# Adding mouse event for secondary mouse button Javafx

Tags: java, mouse, mouseevent, javafx

so i have this anchorpane where i wish to add a mouse listner for the Secondary mouse key ive tried the following but i keep getting an error anyone know what the problem is?

```
   mainDisplayPanel.addEventHandler(MouseButton.SECONDARY, new EventHandler<MouseButton>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseButton event) {
                        System.out.Println("Works");

                    }
                });
```

for the record i have also tried this:

```
            mainDisplayPanel.addEventHandler(MouseButton.SECONDARY, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("WOrks");
                }
            });
```

Stack trace:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method addEventHandler(EventType,
>   EventHandler) of type Node is not applicable for the
>   arguments (MouseButton, new EventHandler(){}). The
>   inferred type MouseButton&Event is not a valid substitute for the
>   bounded parameter

And the other:

> Bound mismatch: The type MouseButton is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type EventHandler

Comment: `System.out.Println("Works");` capital P?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace.

Comment: ...the entire stack trace.

Comment: @Doorknob well i kinda cant compile the code with this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `EventType` based on `MouseButton.SECONDARY`. You need to check the `MouseEvent` itself:

```
mainDisplayPanel.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
           System.out.println("Works");
        }
    }
});
```